# What happened to Nathan Stein and Sarah Goldberg Stein who were living in London 1897?

Tags: united-states, england, russia, jewish, london

On 28 Feb 1897 Nathan/ Nissen Stein, a bootmaker, lived at 27 Winterton Street in London.  He had at least two children:

- a daughter Ada/Ida born about 1877 in; and
- a daughter born about 1893.

Both daughters were born in "Russia" and emigrated to the US.

According to Anna's marriage certificate, her mother was Sara Goldberg but I realize that this may be an error.

This is not the Nathan Stein who was born in Germany.

Winterton Street is the address Nathan Stein listed in the 1897 marriage of his daughter Ada.

I have been unable to find Nathan Stein in the 1901 census which is why I would like to search by address.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Could you edit your question and add a brief list of the sources for the information in your question?  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Is Anna the name of the second daughter born in 1893?  Have you looked for them in the 1901 Census? Was Sara also living at 27 Winterton Street 28 Feb 1897?

Comment: I'm still confused about where "Anna" fits into this - did you perhaps mean to say "Ada"?

Answer (score 2):

Using FindMyPast I was able to locate 27 Winterton Street, London (Registration District of St George in the East) in the 1901 Census and found three households living there:

- 21yo Philip Calinota (spelling?) and his 18yo wife Dora - Prussian Subjects
- 32yo Solomon Cohen, his 30yo wife Golda, and five children aged 6 months - 10 years - Roumanian Subjects
- 33yo Nathan Janovsky, his 32yo wife Sary and their 5yo son Wolf - Prussian Subjects

I could not find anyone with a similar name to Nathan Stein in the nearby pages either.

However, at 81 Old Montague Street, Mile End New Town, Whitechapel, London, which I think is about one mile away, I found a household with:

- Nathan Stein, aged 40, Dock Labourer born in Russia
- Leah Stein, aged 44, born in Russia
- Abraham Stein, aged 21, Tailor, born in Russia

Since you were uncertain about Nathan's wife being Sarah Goldberg, there is a possibility that these are the people you are looking for.  However, Nathan, if born about 1861, would appear very young as the father of Ada, if born about 1877.  His occupation also does not match.

I only found one other Nathan Stein in London for the 1901 Census. He was aged 56, Beer Retailer, born in Germany, and I suspect is the one that you are sure is not yours.  His wife Sarah and eight children were all born in England.